# Application Insight - Unable to get teletry from different environments

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We are experimenting **Azure Application Insight** within a SharePoint 2013 solution. We managed to configure it manually, and we are collecting data from the *development* farm.

However, the same configuration looks like not to be working in the test farm, **as only a few requests are tracked**.

We tried two ways of diagnosing the issue:

1. With a *custom command-line tool* that traces an exception, on the test front-end. No errors are shown, and enabling diagnostic tracing on *System.Net* shows no problem actually occurs in transmission. Eventually, the exception is logged on AppInsight, but not every time.
2. Implementing a *custom WebApi controller* that performs the same action, but within of our solution code. This never gets collected.

In the end, what looks very weird is only certain URL are tracked server-side (no problems with client JS), **which interestingly are the slowest requests**.

I've decompiled all Application Insight assemblies, and of course telemetry transmission in done asynchronusly, but within w3wp.exe there's no chance that the process is aborted and the transmission never occurs...

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can install Fiddler or Other HTTP Debugging tool on the box to see the data that AI sends.
2. To View internal Application Insights traces you can Install PerfView and collect traces:
   **PerfView.exe /onlyProviders=*Microsoft-ApplicationInsights- collect**

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial